# UnboundID LDAP memberof-overlay

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, memberof, unboundid

I'm trying to get the dynamic memberOf attribute to work in my in-memory-ldap-server. I'm using the standard edition of UnboundID.
I tried with the following .ldif-files if it is activated by default:

base.ldif:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: domain
dc: example

dn: ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group

dn: ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: uid=test1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: account
uid: test1

#Group 1.1
dn: cn=testUndergroup,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: testUndergroup    

#Group 1
dn: cn=testgroup,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: testgroup
```

modify.ldif:

```
dn: cn=testgroup,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member: uid=test1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

when i do this ldap-search:
seach:

```
ldapsearch --hostname localhost --port 3268 --baseDN dc=example,dc=com "(uid=test1)" memberOf
```

i dont get the memberof in the answer:

```
# Connected to localhost:3268
dn: uid=test1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

# The search operation was processed successfully.
# Entries returned:  1
# References returned:  0

# Disconnected from the server
```

So it isn't activated by default.

How can i activate the memberOf attribute in UnboundID?

BTW: i can not use dynamic groups like they are mentioned [here](http://community.unboundid.com/t5/Data-Store-Data-Proxy-Data-Sync/Dynamic-Groups/ta-p/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-memory directory server shipped with the LDAP SDK does not support groups. The document that you are referencing on our community portal refers to the UnboundID Directory Server - which is a commercial product and distinct from the in-memory directory server. You can request a free trial download to the UnboundID Directory Server through the main website (https://www.unboundid.com or https://www.pingidentity.com). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for your test-server, like I do, you can just manually add a "memberOf" attribute to the user.

```
dn: uid=test1,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: account
uid: test1
memberOf: testgroup1
memberOf: testgroup2
```